# Getting Error Receiver for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm working on creating my own framework, I added objective c files and its working fine after that I needed to add some swift file after adding swift file xcode is not giving me option of auto **Creating Bridging** then I followed [Mix and Match approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122). I followed everything which I thing I understand.

I want to access swift file into Objective c but I'm getting error of forward declaration so Here is sample code I attached, kindly guide me where I'm doing wrong.

**TestObjectCFile.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class TestSwiftFile;
@interface TestObjCFile : NSObject


@end
```

**TestObjectCFile.m**

```
#import "TestObjCFile.h"
#import <TestFrameworkTry/TestFrameworkTry-Swift.h>
#import "TestFrameworkTry.h"


@implementation TestObjCFile

- (void)TestMethodForImportingSwiftFile
{

    TestSwiftFile * testSwiftFile = [[TestSwiftFile alloc] init];
//    TestSwiftFile * testSwiftFile = [self returnSwiftClassInstance];
    NSLog(@"%@",testSwiftFile);
}
@end
```

**TestSwiftFile.swift**

```
import Foundation
```

And the error occur on **TestObjectCFile.m** following line.

```
TestSwiftFile * testSwiftFile = [[TestSwiftFile alloc] init];
```

as show attached picture.
[image]

Comment: Have you import your Swift bridging file and build your app ?

Comment: I already mentioned that I'm working on Framework and Xcode hasn't this feature in framework.

Comment: Could you show the complete swift code?

Comment: Yes you can see the "TestSwiftFile.swift" in bold is the swift file and this contain only "import Foundation" line of code. Because I just created file and nothing else for testing concept

Comment: If there is no code in Swift, there is nothing to import?!

Comment: No Code because I just created new sample framework to explain the problem in minor scope. Just proof of concept.

Comment: @Aleem Did you got the solution? I facing the same issue in my testfile for framework.

Comment: @PriyankaMistry Yes I found, Here below is my solution. Tell me if you need to know anything.

Comment: @Aleem thanks for your response. :) Actually It was a silly mistake. I was importing file in watch supported umbrella header file and not in ios supported. :D

Comment: @yageek I am also facing the same issue with weScan Library, Can anyone tell me the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally I got solution. I did following changes. Here below is to do list in your Framework.

**Swift classes usage in Objective C classes**

- Use Open Keyword before class name in Swift
- Use @objc Keyword before Open Keyword of Swift class
- Import all header of objective c classes in Umbrella file
  YourProject.h those are consuming Swift Classes.
- Use `#import <YourProjectName/YourProjectName-Swift.h>` in Objective
  c

I followed Apple's Mix and Match approach.

**Note**: sometimes the `<YourProjectName/YourProjectName-Swift.h>` file can not be imported into headers, but only into `.m` files.  FYI, this file is created automatically by the compiler.  If you search your project for it, you won't be able to find it, but if you ⌘ click on it (as a file imported in your code) in a file that is in your target, Xcode will (should) open it and show you all the Objective-C class interfaces for your Swift classes.  To see the name for the Swift -> Objective-C module header, go to your target's Build Settings and search for `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h` or simply `-Swift`.

Comment: can you elaborate the "Import all header of objective c classes in Umbrella file YourProject.h those are consuming Swift Classes." or give a reference for further reading?

Comment: Actually umbrella header is the 'master' header file for a framework. Its use is that you can write and can be available with name "YourProject.h " so you need to list down all those objective c classes's headers those are consume swift classes, and import all those in umbrella file. Make sense ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. This whole thing is a nightmare, not the basics, but when it comes to using different frameworks and the way they interact with Apple frameworks.

Comment: I have tried all but I am still getting error when I imported my code from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2 in xCode 10.1

Comment: What do you mean with "Use Open Keyword before class name in Swift". Can you please explain this ?

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost, basically what it means is your swift class declaration should look like this "@objc open class TestSwiftFile: NSObject {}"

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost `@objc open class YourClassName: NSObject`