# Check isKindOfClass on a Swift Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a mixed project with Obj-C & Swift Classes.
In this project, I wrote a protocol that conforms by 1 Obj-c class (aka class A) and 1 Swift class (aka class B).

Now I wrote a little helper method in Obj-C that checks whether it's kind of class A or B. the problem is that class B getting "**receiver B for class message is forward declaration**".

See code exmple:

```
+ (SomeClass)getProtocol:(NSObject <theProtocol> *)model {

    if ([model isKindOfClass:[A class]]) {
        \\some logic
    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[B class]]) {
        \\some other logic
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

For sure it's something relating to swift inside objective c. is the term **class** available in swift?

Comment: Could you maybe show the declarations for the protocol as well as classes A and B?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800808/getting-error-receiver-for-class-message-is-a-forward-declaration

Comment: In my sample project this compiles without a problem. Did you import the swift file in the objective-c class with the function you wrote in your sample code? `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`

Comment: Forward declarations are fine for headers but you always have to import that specific class to your implementation. I would also say that such usage of protocols seems rather strange. If you have to check that the protocol is of a specific class, then you are losing all the benefits of protocols.

Comment: Avi,
to check 
if ([model isKindOfClass:[A class]]) {
        \\some logic
    } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[B class]]) {
        \\some other logic
    } else {
        return nil;
    }

swift 

if (model is A) {
    some
    logic
}
else if (model is B) {
    some
    other
    logic
}
else {
    return nil
}